Scaleway - timeout when I try to access my instance
I've created a new instance on Scaleway. An IP public is attached on my instance:

I've generated a SSH public / private key pair (with PuTTY Key Generator - type of key "EdDSA"):

Now, I've tried to connect on my FTP with FileZilla:

But I've got an error:
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server

I've already checked IP address, public/private key and all seems to be ok.
I've also tried to connect on my SSH without success.
What's wrong? Have I forgotten something?
